# Domain of a push-forward.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be two smooth manifolds with $\operatorname{dim} M = m$ and $\operatorname{dim} N = n$. Suppose there are open $U \subset M$ and $V \subset N$ and a diffeomorphism $f$ between them:

$$f: U \longrightarrow V.$$

Given $q \in U$, the push-forward $f_{*}$ in $q$ has the domain $T_{q}U$ or $T_{q}M$ ?

Appreciate.

Comment: Strictly speaking, we should take it to be $T_qU$, but really, the two tangent spaces are canonically isomorphic (using the push forward of the inclusion map, $\iota_{*, q}: T_qU \to T_qM $), so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: But if f is a diffeomorphism, $f_{*}$ would be an isomorphism, but then the dimensions of M and N would necessarily have to be equal. It is not?

Comment: If two manifolds have diffeomorphic open subsets then they have the same dimension.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

These two tangent spaces are the same thing, though I'd write $T_q U$ here since $f$ has domain $U$. The definition of tangent space you have is likely something like $T_q U = \{X: C_q^\infty(U) \longrightarrow \mathbb R, X \text{ an }\mathbb R \text{ linear derivation}\}$. Here $C_q^\infty(U)$ is the stalk of smooth functions $U \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ at $q$. Of course, anything involving the stalk is independent of the choice of open neighborhood of $q$.

Comment: I posted this as a comment to your original post, but it is true that manifolds with diffeomorphic open subsets have the same dimension.